# LotusNotes Script: backup All server database

Tags: lotus-notes

today i tried to do a copy of a database(design and documents) by doing right click on database-> New copy... and i see that the new copy of database have smallest dimension of the source database (source database 900mb and the new copy 170mb).
I see also that if i access in the new copy of this database the size passes form 170mb to 400mb (i think is because notes create index...)
But i need to copy database only to create a backup so the size is important because i have to do daily backup and to consulted it only in particoular case.

So i built an agent to do this copy but the result is not the same, the new copy have the same dimension of the source database.
**Is there a trick to obtain the same "compression" of right click on database-> New copy...  but with script code ?**

I post the code that i use but without  that compression:

```
Dim Db As NotesDatabase
    Dim Ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim Session As New NotesSession
    Dim DbDir As NotesDbDirectory
    Dim AllDocs As NotesView
    Dim SourceDb As NotesDatabase   
    Dim ArchiveDb As NotesDatabase
    Dim SourceDoc As NotesDocument
    Set Db=Session.CurrentDatabase      
    Set DbDir=Session.GetDbDirectory(Db.Server) 
    Set SourceDb = DbDir.GetFirstDatabase(DATABASE)

    Do While Not SourceDb Is Nothing                    
            Print"BackUp Database "+Cstr(SourceDb.FileName)
            Gosub BackUpDatabase
        Set SourceDb = DbDir.GetNextDatabase
    Loop
    Exit Sub    
BackUpDatabase:
    If SourceDb.IsOpen=False Then Call SourceDb.Open( "", "" )
    Set ArchiveDb = SourceDb.CreateCopy( "", "C:\Test\"+Cstr(Day(Date))+"-"+Cstr(Month(Date))+"-"+Cstr(Year(Date))+"\"+SourceDb.FilePath)

    Set AllDocs = SourceDb.CreateView( "@AllDocs", "SELECT @All" )  
    Set SourceDoc=AllDocs.GetFirstDocument      

    Do While Not SourceDoc Is Nothing
        Call SourceDoc.CopyToDatabase(ArchiveDb)
        Set SourceDoc=AllDocs.GetNextDocument(SourceDoc)
    Loop
    Call AllDocs.Remove()
    Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "compression" as you call it is simply the "absence" of view- indices. 
The database size consists of:

1. Size of all documents
2. Size of the design of the database
3. Empty Space (if data was deleted, but the database not compacted)
4. View indices

A new copy (via client) has NO indices, but as soon as you open a view, the size of the database will increase.

Your script is NOT a good idea for a backup:

1. All documents get a new Creation Stamp
2. All documents get a new replica id - Response- hierarchies will be completely lost after your copy

etc.

If you really want to go that direction, then you woould have to compact the database using a compact -D to get the free space and the view indices back,
but I would never do a backup of a production database like this...

Another (better) possibility would be to create a new replica with LotusScript- code and make a backup of that:

```vb
Set ArchiveDb = SourceDb.CreateReplica( "", "C:\Test\"+Cstr(Day(Date))+"-"+Cstr(Month(Date))+"-"+Cstr(Year(Date))+"\"+SourceDb.FilePath)
```

If you keep that database after doing the backup, then you might want to change the replica- id of the database using this code:

```vb
Option Public
Option Declare

Const wAPIModule = "NNOTES" ' Windows/32

Type API_TIMEDATE
  lngInnards(1) As Long
End Type
Type API_DBREPLICAINFO
  ID As API_TIMEDATE  'ID that is same for all replica files
  intFlags As Integer     'Replication flags
  intCutoffInterval As Integer   'Automatic Replication Cutoff
  Cutoff As API_TIMEDATE       'Replication cutoff date
End Type

Declare Private Function NSFDbOpen Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbOpen" _
( ByVal P As String, hDB As Long) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFDbClose Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbClose" _
( ByVal hDB As Long) As Integer

Declare Private Function NSFDbReplicaInfoGet Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbReplicaInfoGet" _
(ByVal hdb As Long, hdbr As API_DBREPLICAINFO) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFDbReplicaInfoSet Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbReplicaInfoSet" _
(ByVal hdb As Long, hdbr As API_DBREPLICAINFO) As Integer
Sub ChangeReplicaID( strServer As String, strFilePath As String, strReplicaID As String )

  Dim intRc As Integer
  Dim lngDb As Long

  Dim RepInfo As API_DBREPLICAINFO     

  If strServer = "" Then
    intRc = NSFDbOpen( strFilePath, lngDb )
  Else
    intRc = NSFDbOpen( strServer & "!!" & strFilePath, lngDb )
  End If  

  If intRc <> 0 Then
    MessageBox "Could not open DB"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  intRc = NSFDbReplicaInfoGet(lngDb, RepInfo)

  If intRc <> 0 Then
    MessageBox "Could not get replication info"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  RepInfo.ID.lngInnards(1) = Val( "&H"+Left$( strReplicaID, 8 ) )
  RepInfo.ID.lngInnards(0) = Val( "&H"+Right$( strReplicaID, 8 ) )

  intRc = NSFDbReplicaInfoSet( lngDb, RepInfo)    ' take a deep breath...   :-)

  intRc = NSFDbReplicaInfoGet( lngDb, RepInfo)
  If intRc <> 0 Then
    MessageBox "Could not get replication info after setting"
  Else
    MessageBox "Success"
  End If  
End Sub
```

But the best advice I can give: Use a professional Backup- Software to do that job.